# HighchartsTable jQuery plugin - is it possible to have labels on axis-Y and values on axis-X

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

when I create a column chart using jQuery HighchartsTable plugin (not jason based highchart), the labels are on axis-X and values are on axis-Y by default.

I need the reverse, I have many long labels, they don't fit horizontally .
is it possible to have labels on axis-Y and values on axis-X ?

Thanks.

P.S. And can I replace word "Valeur" with my own ? :)

Comment: Why don't you simple invert how you set values ?

Comment: Have you any live demo of it ?

Comment: http://pmsipilot.github.com/jquery-highchartTable-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set inverted parameter as true

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about "HighchartsTable" plugin

Comment: Thank you! highchartTable didn't have this param thru the attributes.